# Why ajax call is very slow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I was calling an ajax function on load page event. When I load the page, in the server log, There was not existing call log(I log entrance and out on all mvc server method). The request from javascript to server was taking some time, 2 to 3 minutes. The strange thing is when I test it local and test server, it works well. It occurs just when I deploy a project to the real server!

I found some posts about the method to do ajax, xmlhttp, $.ajax(). I already used both. But It still exists.

This is my javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: allservicesUrl,
        async: true,
        success: function(result, status, xhr){
            var services = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            for (i in services) {
                createServicecard(services[i]);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
})
```

I wanna execute it immediately. How do I correct this problem?

Comment: Ah.... hmm.... there is some unclear thing. The request from javascript does not come to the server.

Comment: Yes, right. But the response from the server was not slow and no lack. When the request from javascript comes to the server, the response was fast and normal.

Comment: the delay is because the request isn't made until the "document" is "ready" - maybe you have something that takes a long time to load. if `createServicecard` relies on the "document" being "ready", then the only solution is to make that (document ready) happen quicker - the delay would be caused by something OTHER than the code you've shown

Comment: But... when I deploy it on the real server, the one PC loaded this page fast and other PC slow...

Comment: no idea - perhaps some cached content from some other server - seriously it's not going to be anything in the code you posted - you'll need to check the browser developer tools console or network tabs to see if any resource is taking a long time to load, and investigate this yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice.

I saw an answer and comments. Then, I saw the dev tool(network tab), finally, I found the problem.

Now I correct it, it works well. Thank you very much.

ps. Problem: connecting the internet in closed network.

Answer (score -1):

Use the debugging/developer tools in your browser to trouble shoot this issue.
look in the console and see if you have any JS errors, then look in the network tab. Clear the entries and then reload the AJAX call.

you should be able to see if your script is slow to send the request to the server or if the server is slow to answer.

until you figure out if the bottleneck is in the script or on the server you can't fix it.